# No output when rendering GeoJSON using Leaflet() package in RShiny

Tags: r, leaflet, geojson

I am creating a Rshiny interface on that can take in the user input when a user click on a point on the map, query the user's selection from postgresql and return another map layer. The package I am using is leaflet. (https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/). I have followed the examples, but am unable to generate any map layers.

The following are my ui.r and server.r codes

**ui.r**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title here"),

  sidebarLayout(position = "right", 
     sidebarPanel(
       selectInput("time", 
                   label = "Choose a time period",
                   choices = list("1", "2", "3")
     )
   ),

  mainPanel(leafletOutput('map'))
))
```

**server.r**

```
shinyServer(function(input,output) {


  drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
  con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="postgres",host="localhost",user=***, password=***, port=5432)
  geojson_fromsql <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT ST_ASGeoJson(geom) FROM table WHERE time='input';)

  geojson <- fromJSON("file path/file name.geojson")

  map <- leaflet() %>%  
    addTiles() %>%
    addGeoJson(geojson)

  output$map <- renderLeaflet(map)

}
```

**geojson** gives me the following:

```
$type
[1] "Feature Collection"

$crs 
$crs$type 
[1] "name"

$crs$properties 
                         name
"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CR84"

 $features
 $features[[1]]
 $features[[1]]$type
 [1] "Feature"

 $features[[1]]$properties 

 year 
 "2012"

 $features[[1]]$geometry
 $features[[1]]$geometry$type 
 [1] "Point"

 $features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates
 [1] 103.77749    1.28983

 ...

 $features
 $features[[17]]
 $features[[17]]$type
 [1] "Feature"

 $features[[17]]$properties 

 year 
 "2012"

 $features[[17]]$geometry
 $features[[17]]$geometry$type 
 [1] "Point"

 $features[[17]]$geometry$coordinates
 [1] 103.67749    1.32983
```

while **geojson_sql** has the following structure:

```
(data.frame) 
                                        st_asgeojson
1{"type":"Point","coordinates":[103.77748, 1.28983]}
...
17{"type":"Point","coordinates":[103.67749, 1.32983]}
```

*addGeoJson(geojson)* gives me nothing in the main panel (fig 1). *addGeoJson(geojson_sql) gives a leaflet widget, with no tilelayers (fig 2). *addGeoJson(geojson_sql[1,]) gives a leaflet widget, with no tilelayers as well (fig 2). I believe I have some syntax errors in setting the tilelayer as well.

But more importantly, I would like to know what format/structure does the leaflet package accept for geojson, and how I can derive it in R?

PS: Suggestions for alternative packages or methods are welcome too. I have tried rCharts and have hit a wall here as well: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151536/how-to-convert-a-geojson-from-postgresql-to-geojson-format-readable-in-rcharts-i
And I am not certain that rCharts takes in the user's input when users click on points on the map.

fig 1 - reading geojson directly into R
[image: fig 1 - reading geojson directly into R]

fig 2 - reading geojson from postgresql
[image: fig 2 - reading geojson from postgresql]

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand what you want to accomplish from the user clicking on the map. But in regards to rendering the map layers, if you want to use `addGeoJSON()` I think it is easiest to read in the json file as follows:

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){

  geojson <- reactive({
    readLines("filename.json") %>% paste(collapse = "\n")
    })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addGeoJson(geojson())
    })
})
```

You can change the code inside `reactive()` to include your user input such as `input$time` in order to change the geojson that is read in. Note the parenthesis after geojson in the last line.